# SwiftUI Image not showing properly as an overlay

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a custom "sign in with apple" button:

```
Button(action: {
    
}) {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32)
        .frame(height: 48)
        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
        .overlay(
            HStack {
                Image("apple.white")
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                Spacer()
                Text("Sign in with Apple")
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
    )
        .padding(.horizontal)
}
```

It looks fine as a static RoundedRectangle:
[image]

But it won't show properly as an overlay to the button:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because SwiftUI tints buttons by default, try adding:

```
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

to the button.